# JAVA set Garbage collection options

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I want to get GC logs from a program which runs on top of JVM. I know its possible to get those using

```
-Xloggc:GCLog.txt  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseSerialGC
```

parameters when running the application using

```
java -jar "jar_file".
```

But in this case I can't run the program in this manner by giving arguments, instead is there a way to specify them before running the application?

For an example we can set `Xmx`, `Xms` values using export

```
JVM_MEM_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx100m"
```

before running the java application.) Is there a similar way to specify GC parameters before running the application.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like there is a wrapper to the java exec. Have you added the specified GC JVM flags to the JVM_MEM_OPTS variable and are there other environment variables in the java wrapper; e.g. JAVA_OPTS ? You need to review the java wrapper and how the java executable is being invoked.

Comment: JVM **does not** read `JVM_MEM_OPTS` variable. It is a job of Java launcher to start JVM with certain arguments. Since you use non-standard Java launcher, you need to consult the documentation to that launcher. How did you know about `JVM_MEM_OPTS`?

Comment: HotSpot JVM reads `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variables. You may try one of these.

Answer (score 1):

> For an example we can set Xmx, Xms values using export
>
> JVM_MEM_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx100m"

This way is not standard and not referenced in the Java documentation.
`JVM_MEM_OPTS`, `JAVA_OPTS` or any environment variable will set the JVM options only because the tool/program that you use to start the JVM transmit it in the JVM options of the `java` command that is executed.
For example `JAVA_OPTS` is recognized in the Tomcat scripts (especially `catalina.sh/bat)`.

`-Xms100m -Xmx100m` as  `-Xloggc:GCLog.txt  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseSerialGC` are [JVM options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).
If you don't want to pass directly these options in the java command, you have to do as the tools that allows to use a custom environment variable : create a script (specific to the OS) that uses this environment variable as value of the JVM options such as (linux way):

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar "jar_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I need to know is whether there is an option such as export JVM_MEM_OPTS to set gc parameters.

Comment: The reason is I can't start my program as java -jar. It uses a different command, but under neath it uses Java